# Are Demon Hunter pets valid targets?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

My spider I have from being a Demon Hunter does not have a life bar. Can they be targeted, killed, status effected etc.? Or are they just a dot on wheels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Demon Hunters pet is, as you put it, 'a dot on wheels'. They cannot be attacked or interacted with in any way, but are instead simply a fire and forget source of extra damage (and buffs!)

Answer (score 1):

Your pet will only die if you are killed. Enemies cannot target them at all. Once activated, they will simply serve as a distraction while dishing out extra damage.